# Restrict Crontab job between a particular interval

Tags: cron

I have a ruby file and I need to run it once in every 3 hours. 
This code works fine:

```
27 */3 * * * /path/to/ruby -rubygems /path/to/ruby_file.rb
```

And I don't want this file to run between midnight 12.00 to morning 8.00

How can I set it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`27 9-23/3 * * *` should work on most modern variants of Unix.

Answer (score 1):

```
27 9-23/3 * * * /path/to/ruby -rubygems /path/to/ruby_file.rb
```

should do the trick.

A good summary of it all can be found in [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Answer (score 1):

```
*/15    10-20   *       *       *       /usr/bin/php /tmp/myscript.php

*/6     6-9,21-23,0-2   *       *       *       /usr/bin/php /tmp/myscript.php
```

More complex cron for you my friend.
Notice: cron do not jump over 23-0

Answer (score 0):

2-10/4 like 2,8 or 2,6,10 ?

I think the seconds