# How can I schedule a script to run every 46 minutes, between 6:00 am and 23:40pm, daily with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apscheduler

I need a script to run every 46 minutes, between 6:00 am and 23:40pm, daily. Im currently using apscheduler, but I'm failing to set up the 24 runs per day on interval schedule, and programming each one of the run with a cron mode seems highly inefficient. Is there a simple way of telling python to "run this code every 46 minutes, 24 times a day, starting at 6am?"

Comment: What you want is a cron job which will trigger your python program

Comment: yeah, but how do I add intervals to the cron job?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6248662/1005215

Comment: It looks like apscheduler is a good approach for you.  If you post your existing scheduling code and what it's not doing and how you will handle any downtime you will probably get better help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're not using asyncio, gevent, tornado, etc.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

sched = BackgroundScheduler()
sched.start()
sched.add_job(function, 'cron', minute='46' hour='6-23')
```

See the [docs](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/triggers/cron.html?highlight=cron#module-apscheduler.triggers.cron) for more details.

EDIT:

Misread the question. I'm assuming you wanted every 46 minutes, not AT the 46th minute every hour between 6 to 23. It would probably be better to have apscheduler event that stops an interval job at 23 and resumes it again at 6.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
sched = BackgroundScheduler()

def disable_interval():
    sched.remove_job('INTERVAL_JOB')

def enable_interval():
    sched.add_job(run_function, 'interval', minutes=46, id='INTERVAL_JOB')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sched.start()
    sched.add_job(enable_interval, 'cron', minute='0' hour='6')
    sched.add_job(disable_interval, 'cron', minute='40' hour='23')
```

Comment: Updated my code because I misread your question the first time. Basically the updated code creates a new job at 6:00 that runs every 46 minutes. At 23:40, it removes the job. This should work as intended but I don't have apscheduler installed right now so I can't test it. Mess around with the code a bit and you should get what you want.